# Why is this light kit not working?

Tags: wiring, ceiling, light-fixture

I recently bought a new light kit to attach to my ceiling fan. The connections sounded pretty simple. I attached blue wire from the ceiling fan wires to the black wire in the light kit and the white wire to the white wire in the light kit as shown in the picture.

[image]

This sounds pretty simple but I have no clue why the lights are not working. Any help in figuring out why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the blue wire from the ceiling fan connected to anything in the ceiling?

Comment: @brhans No. It directly comes from the ceiling wires. I mean that was one of the wires that came out of the ceiling and it was capped separately when I opened the housing.

Comment: Those wires in your pic come from the *ceiling fan*. I'm asking about where the *other end* of that blue wire goes when it leaves the top end of the ceiling fan and goes into the ceiling - because I'm guessing it's not connected to anything up there.

Comment: Is it connected to the switch?